# Python not working in Linux shared hosting server

Tags: python, linux

I trying to setup python as scripting language in my Linux shared hosting server. I have followed [this link](http://blog.arvixe.com/create-your-own-python-enviroment-locally-in-your-shared-hosting-account/) to setup **python 2.6.4** in my server.

I have followed same steps as there, and everything worked fine but still I am not able to execute python files.

**For Example:**

I have created a file under `public_html/index.py` with following code

```
#!/home/explore/bin/python

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"

print "Hello World!"
```

But when I am opening this file in browser, its just coming in simple TEXT.

Please Help

Comment: try first running your script using `/home/explore/bin/python index.py` to see if that works.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
index.py , line 1

Comment: Why install an obsolescent version? If you really want Python 2, you should definitely consider 2.7 for new deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you badly wrote your script first line… That line is called a [*shebang*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), which a human readable [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) to identify a script:

```
#!/home/explore/bin/python
```

she (derivating from *sha*, *hash*) for the pound sign: `#`

and bang for the exclamation mark: `!`

Comment: Thanks for the correction but still I am only able to see output in Shell terminal, but not in Browser

Comment: well, it's out of scope for stack overflow, and you're not giving enough information to get help. Please ask again on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), and ***there***, tell what is your hosting service, what is your web server, and how did you configure your web server in your question.

Comment: `/home/explore/bin/python index.py` This gives me error **file not found**, so I am using `/home/explore/bin/python /home/explore/public_html/index.py`